# How to optimize this expression ? LINQ?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, optimization

It looks scary but it works.. now I would like to find a better way to implement this.

I have a app that provides booking for sports center with basketball, tennis court, volleyball and football. When someone is creating new reservation, I want to check if there is no other reservation for that discipline (sport) at time selected by user, or when someone is editing his/her reservation, he/she didn't choose already booked playing field.

I get count of all records that meet requirements.  If there are no records, I assume that selected time and discipline does not interrupt with any other already selected.  If there are records, it means that there exists a reservation at that facility in selected time

There is a relation between tables Discipline and Event so goind through my code there is:

**n.Discipline.disciplineId == disciplineId** -  id number of selected discipline

**n.eventId != eventId** - for editing I want to exclude records that are being edited because if user is not editing discipline but somethings else it still returns row as a conflict

**n.eventStart.Day == eventStart.Day** - Without this comparison, records with other days but matching hours are returned

**(( n.eventEnd <= eventStart  || eventStart <= n.eventStart)&&( n.eventEnd <= eventEnd || eventEnd <= n.eventStart))** - main dates comparison.  Maybe it could be replace with some between statement but I can't find how to use that for my code.

```
db.Events.Where(n => n.Discipline.disciplineId == disciplineId && (n.eventId != eventId) && (n.eventStart.Day == eventStart.Day) && (( n.eventEnd <= eventStart  || eventStart <= n.eventStart)&&( n.eventEnd <= eventEnd || eventEnd <= n.eventStart))))
```

Is there a way to improve this code or optimize it? Can LINQ give me a better result?  I'm worried about what will happen when the database grows.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just add in some line breaks and spaces and the code is fine.  The only real problem with it is that you tried to shove it all into one line.  While there are other things you can do, adding whitespace effectively is likely, "good enough".

Comment: line break before each `&&` and remove a lot of those unecessary parenthesis makes it pretty readable.  Check out the [order of operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Personally I think the way you're going about this is wrong. Why are you sending tons of information to the client in order to verify data? Why don't you just send parameters to a stored procedure on the database, have the database do the verifying, and then return a bit (bool) to the client? This would be far more efficient, secure, and you get the added benefits of being able to maintain the verification method without needing to update the application (unless extra parameters are required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't really need the records, but just want to know if one (or more) records exist, using Any will significantly reduce the query in many cases, exitting on first matching record.

I also simplified the range intersection check for you.  Since we are no longer using .Day which is part of datetime, the result should be able to be returned from the server instead of client-side, and should be able to take advantage of any indexes placed on those fields.

```
if (db.Events.Any(n => n.Discipline.disciplineId == disciplineId 
   && (n.eventId != eventId) 
   && (n.eventStart <= eventEnd) 
   && (eventStart <= n.eventEnd)))
```

You could rewrite this in a more LINQish way like this as well, but it's the same thing:

```
if (db.Events
   .Where(n=>n.eventId != eventId)
   .Where(n=>n.eventStart<=eventEnd)
   .Where(n=>eventStart<=n.eventEnd)
   .Any(n.Discipline.disciplineId==disciplineId))
```

Comment: You might also want to read this https://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/finding-intersecting-ranges-using-expression-trees-and-the-entity-framework/ which would add a range intersection extension method for you, which might make it a bit more readable for you.

Comment: Thank for answer, not getting records is best practise for this.